# Facebook like open graph meta tags required when liking an Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I hope that this question ends up in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook* section. Well, i have a question about the like button and a facebook page.

Until now i have been using an simple like button and open graph meta tags for the markup, the URL to be liked was https://www.MY_URL.se/.

Now that i have created an Facebook page i will change the URL to be liked to https://www.facebook.com/MY_FACEBOOK_PAGE.

**The question is then, is the open graph meta tags required in my HTML or can i just remove these? Will the information in the like be filled with the content from my Facebook page instead, for example the profile picture, the description and so on?**

I can't figure out a way to test this with an test-user nor i want to try it out live and find it to be not working as intended so hence why i'm asking.

Comment: _“nor i want to try it out live and find it to be not working as intended”_ – why not? If it doesn’t turn out the way you want to … _what’s the worst that could happen?_

Comment: @CBroe - It's a business page so it might have an negative inpact if the information displayed in the Like is not working properly.

Comment: Impact on what? If you don’t like what your own like of the page is showing, then just remove it from your timeline …

Comment: @CBroe Sadly this might still go out to a big number of potential customers even when deleted shortly afterwards.

Comment: How is anything that happens on your own personal timeline going out to customers?

Comment: @Cbroe I'm the site developer, business owner, site admin, Facebook business page admin and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any new likes will grab content from https://www.facebook.com/MY_FACEBOOK_PAGE. The old likes (as far as I know) will still point to the old content https://www.MY_URL.se/.

So, your like count will not be cumulative across the two pages.

Comment: I see, thank you for clearing that out for me. I managed to find a route to actually try it out with a test user for an app and you are correct.